# If `zip` were a method of a lawful type class, of which then?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

**why the question**   One may say that `zip` is a method of `Applicative`, the usual instance being [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList). I am unhappy with it because it is unsafe. I am unhappy with [`Align`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-Align.html) too, because it is, by virtue of being all-encompassing, overly complicated and not specific enough for usual cases.

**lawful classes**   Some type classes in Haskell may be dubbed *lawful*. This means that they come with equalities that must hold — the laws for a class. It is ordinary that these laws come from category theoretic conceptualization of an aspect of programming. For example, `Monad` is a conceptualization of *computations* *(whatever is meant by that)* via the eponymous category theory device.

**overlaying things**   The usual operation to want to do with boxes of things is to lay them on top of each other, and if they are monoid, they will meld.

Examples:

- [Arithmetics with Maybe.](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2017-09-25-applicative-arithmetic.html)
- [Addition of matrices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition)

**not enough laws**   The conceptualization of this concept is via monoidal functors, and the corresponding `Applicative` type class. There is, however, an annoying complication in that there are very often two ways to define the `Applicative` that both appear suitable. Why so? I propose that the answer is *"not enough laws"*.

Examples:

- For arithmetics:

  - The `Sum` monoid is the actual *"endo-monoid"*. It is only legal for kin things. You cannot sum mass and force, for instance.
  - The `Product` monoid takes numbers of dimension `a` & `b` to a number of dimension `c`. Multiplying mass and force is legal and gets us to warmth.

  So, the right choice of monoid may be inferred from types.
- For lists:

  - The usual [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of lists is the more safe one. It works with any finite number of elements trivially, and with co-finite number thereof with a *"diagonal process"* definition such as [LogicT](http://okmij.org/ftp/papers/LogicT.pdf).
  - The `ZipList` definition is clearly unsafe. It is defined to, given two lists of distinct length, crop the longer one to the length of the shorter.
  - Length indexed vectors are the device that allows for a safe definition of `zip`, by demanding a proof that the given lists are of same length.
- For matrices:

  - The usual addition of matrices has the *(very reasonable)* requirement of dimension homogeneity, the same as with length indexed vectors mentioned above. Since matrices are habitually used in various real world simulations, such as 3D graphics, once matrices begin to get cropped or zero-padded, people would complain quite immediately, so a `ZipMatrix` definition along the lines of `ZipList` above does not appear attractive.
  - The stranger [Kronecker multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is reminiscent of the direct product of lists. And it admits the definition of `Monad`, too.

**two cases**   From these examples, it reveals itself that there are two distinct ideas mixed up in the thing we call a *"monoid"* or a *"monoidal functor"*, and the distinction is *very* important for programming *(unlike, perhaps, pure theory)* because it would clean up confusion, remove unsafeties and, primarily, because there are, in each case, *two completely unrelated algorithms to run*.

---

I am thinking that maybe invertibility *(also called* "strength"*)* of the monoidal functor is what matters. But the results of the Sum and the Product monoidal operation on Peano naturals are indistinguishable. *(I am unsure whether they can be considered monoidal endofunctors.)* So, I am turned to a guess that the changing of types is the hallmark. Multiplication of physical quantities does not type check as a `Monoid`, even!

**P.S.** There presents itself an instance of `Monad` for length indexed vectors over cartesian products and for matrices over Kronecker multiplication, with some sort of `fold zip` as `join`.

Comment: What do you mean by invertible? The obvious definition is something like "if `liftA2 (,) xs ys == liftA2 (,) xs' ys'`, then `xs == xs'` and `ys == ys'`". But the usual `Applicative` instance for lists (which I think you're calling the "direct sum"), which you claim is invertible, does not satisfy this definition (e.g. `liftA2 (,) [] [()] == liftA2 (,) [()] []`), so I'm unclear on exactly what you want here. (And this is not a quibble about emptiness: there are also non-empty lists which break invertibility.)

Comment: "One may say that `zip` is a method of `Applicative`". Why? And *all* monids are "endo-monoids"; the definition starts with a single type and a *closed* binary operation on that type.

Comment: @chepner Well, maybe the usual `Hask` understanding of "monoid" must be expanded. For instance, length indexed vectors are an obvious monoid, it is just that there is a type level _(also monoidal)_ operation involved in the definition of `mappend`. Notice also that a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors.

Comment: @chepner Because `zip` is `liftA2 (,)` in `Control.Appicative.ZipList`. Also, because `Applicative` actually somewhat stands for "monoidal functor", and the [definition thereof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) would strike you with its similarity to the type of `zip`.

Comment: @DanielWagner By _"invertible"_ I mean that _arrows can be retracted_. Observe also the definition of a strong monoidal functor, say, [at nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) or [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) _(which `Applicative` is, contrary to Hackage, [not](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/12414/48223))_. Your example mandates that I, at the very least, add "non-trivial" somewhere in the corresponding passage of my post. However, I am not sure I am able to discover the non-trivial pathological cases you are mentioning.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov For example, take any `m /= n` and consider that `liftA2 (,) (replicate m x) (replicate n y) == liftA2 (,) (replicate n x) (replicate m y)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh, you are right. I will be thinking it through.

Comment: Thinking about vectors and matrices there are possibly operations to be made from a binary operation than you’ve considered. As well as the Cartesian product kind (`(a -> b -> c) -> v n a -> v m b -> v (n * m) c`) and the zip kind (`(a -> b -> c) -> v n a -> v n b -> v n c`), there is a contraction kind for matrices: `Monoid c => (`a -> b -> c) -> m x y a -> m y z b -> m x z c`. That said I think the right place for this would be a shape-indexed applicative. This works for vectors which are obviously zippable and the size is easily expressed. It also works for functions. It doesn’t for maps.

Comment: I can't write a proper answer right now, but anyway: (1) FWIW, I don't think of `ZipList` zipping as unsafe; rather, I see it and the "safe" zipping you describe as variations on the same theme (it helps that the trimming performed by ordinary `zip` is useful sometimes). (2) That said, one option is [`Representable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) -- have a look at `mzipRep` -- which limits us to things with fixed shape (fixed size vectors, infinite streams, functions, etc.).

Comment: @duplode I am encouraging you to write an answer at a later time then. It will take me a while to decipher the documentation to this module you linked, and there may as well be someone else interested in the same question, who will most certainly enjoy reading your answer too.

Comment: For matrix addition, zero-padding is actually quite a sensible thing to do: dynamically-sized matrices represent finite-rank linear mappings ℝ^∞ → ℝ^∞, and if one is shorter than the other it simply means that its other entries are taken to be zero. The reason most data languages (of the Matlab tradition) throw an error when adding matrices of different dimension is that they don't have a proper type system. The proper representation of “matrices” in a well-typed language like Haskell is as a [category of linear mappings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category).

Comment: Reading through the question again, I don't think it's really focused sensibly. You first start about applicatives, but then make your bullet points about monoids instead. Keep in mind that “monoidal functor” doesn't really have much to do with `Monoid`: the former refers to the single _type-level monoid_ (`()`, `(,)`), the latter to various value-level monoids among Haskell types.

Comment: Apart from that, I don't understand your objection about `ZipList` being “unsafe”. It has the semantics of a zip which means you drop elements, fine. That's just how it works. If you don't want to even allow different-length zipping to typecheck, well, you'll need a suitable fixed-length type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I am not sure I am ready to agree. (1) _"That's just how it works"_ may be said about implicit state and pointer arithmetics, too. (2) I am thinking that a tuple is an instance of a free monoid, like a list or an hlist. Specifically, one usually puts things `x :: A` and `y :: B` in a tuple `(x, y)` because a function `f :: A -> B -> C` will be available at a later time that will meld them. So, one may as well wrap them in `data W = WA A | WB B | WC C` and define an `instance Monoid W where mappend (WA x) (WB y) = WC $ f x y`. Does this justify my argument better?

Comment: "Not enough laws" will always be a problem for `Applicative`, because every single `Applicative` type also allows an `Applicative` instance which goes the other way. See `Control.Applicative.Backwards`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exact zipping (as the [*safe*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.17/docs/Safe-Exact.html) package calls it) can be expressed through [the `Representable` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html). There is a fair amount of theory associated with `Representable`. For our current purposes, we can focus on...

> A `Functor` `f` is `Representable` if `tabulate` and `index` witness an isomorphism to `(->) x`.

... and:

> Representable endofunctors over the category of Haskell types are isomorphic to the reader monad and so inherit a very large number of properties for free.

Since `Representable` functors are isomorphic to functions from some type (e.g. an homogeneous pair is isomorphic to `Bool -> a`, and an infinite stream is isomorphic to `Nat -> a`), exact zipping can be achieved by zipping the functions pointwise. That is what [`mzipRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#v:mzipRep), the default implementation for `MonadZip`'s `mzip`, does:

```
mzipRep :: Representable f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
mzipRep as bs = tabulate (index as &&& index bs)
```

While [`MonadZip` is a rather awkward class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Zip.html) (it is primarily part of the implementation of the `MonadComprehensions` extension), it has a relevant law, which I will restate it in non-monadic terms:

> Information preservation: if `() <$ u = () <$ v` then `munzip (mzip u v) = (u, v)`

In other words, if `u` and `v` have the same shape, then `mzip` does not drop information (and so it can be undone by `munzip`). As `Representable` implies there being just one possible shape, it allows us to drop the condition, thus getting exact zipping.

---

Tangential notes:

> The `ZipList` definition is clearly unsafe. It is defined to, given two lists of distinct length, crop the longer one to the length of the shorter.

I'd say that depends on what you want to use zipping for. Sometimes you will want or need exact zipping, and sometimes you won't (for instance, consider the commonplace trick of attaching indices to a list with `zip [0..]`); and sometimes padding rather than trimming will be what makes sense (cf. [leftaroundabout's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910125/if-zip-were-a-method-of-a-lawful-type-class-of-which-then?noredirect=1#comment90813346_51910125)). That is why I prefer calling exact zipping "exact", rather than "safe".

> There is, however, an annoying complication in that there are very often two ways to define the `Applicative` that both appear suitable. Why so? I propose that the answer is *"not enough laws"*.

I very much disagree with the view that a class is underspecified if it allows more than one instance for some data type. I'd rather say that e.g. lists with the cartesian product applicative and lists with the zipping applicative are different structures, characterised by the relevant morphisms -- it just happens that they can be represented in Haskell through the same data type.

Comment: From what you say, it must be very easy to obtain an `instance Representable` for a container with two elements _(`Bool -> a`)_, or with infinite number of elements _(`Natural -> a`)_, but I wonder to what type of functions an `instance Representable (Vector (n :: Nat))` would correspond _(Where `Vector` and `Nat` are similar to those I outlined in a [nearby question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51917531))_. Do we have a suitable type _(like, `FinOrd (n :: Nat)`?..)_ in Haskell?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov That is feasible indeed. Cf. for instance [*finite-typelits*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits-0.1.4.2/docs/Data-Finite.html), which in turn can be used to implement fixed size vectors [with an exact `zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized-1.0.4.0/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html#g:22) in the style of what Dan Robertson suggested [in a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910125/if-zip-were-a-method-of-a-lawful-type-class-of-which-then/51950729?noredirect=1#comment90773575_51910125).