# How do I apply inductive reasoning to `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`?

Tags: haskell, type-families, induction

Consider this definition of `zip` for the usual vectors length indexed by Peano numerals:

```
{-# language DataKinds          #-}
{-# language KindSignatures     #-}
{-# language GADTs              #-}
{-# language TypeOperators      #-}
{-# language StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# language FlexibleInstances  #-}
{-# language FlexibleContexts   #-}

module Vector
  where

import Prelude hiding (zip)

data N
  where
    Z :: N
    S :: N -> N

data Vector (n :: N) a
  where
    VZ :: Vector Z a
    (:::) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a

infixr 1 :::

deriving instance Show a => Show (Vector n a)

class Zip z
  where
    zip :: z a -> z b -> z (a, b)

instance Zip (Vector n) => Zip (Vector (S n))
  where
    zip (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) = (x, y) ::: zip xs ys

instance Zip (Vector Z)
  where
    zip _ _ = VZ

-- ^
-- λ :t zip (1 ::: 2 ::: 3 ::: VZ) (4 ::: 5 ::: 6 ::: VZ)
-- zip (1 ::: 2 ::: 3 ::: VZ) (4 ::: 5 ::: 6 ::: VZ)
--   :: (Num a, Num b) => Vector ('S ('S ('S 'Z))) (a, b)
-- λ zip (1 ::: 2 ::: 3 ::: VZ) (4 ::: 5 ::: 6 ::: VZ)
-- (1,4) ::: ((2,5) ::: ((3,6) ::: VZ))
```

Typing in unary numbers is wearysome *(even though I have a macro for that)*. Fortunately, there is `GHC.TypeLits`. Let us use it:

```
module Vector
  where

import Prelude hiding (zip)
import GHC.TypeLits

data Vector (n :: Nat) a
  where
    VZ :: Vector 0 a
    (:::) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a

infixr 1 :::

deriving instance Show a => Show (Vector n a)

class Zip z
  where
    zip :: z a -> z b -> z (a, b)

instance Zip (Vector n) => Zip (Vector (n + 1))
  where
    zip (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) = (x, y) ::: zip xs ys

instance Zip (Vector 0)
  where
    zip _ _ = VZ
```

— But no:

```
    • Illegal type synonym family application in instance:
        Vector (n + 1)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Zip (Vector (n + 1))’
   |
28 | instance Zip (Vector n) => Zip (Vector (n + 1))
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I replace the class with an ordinary function:

```
zip :: Vector n a -> Vector n b -> Vector n (a, b)
zip (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) = (x, y) ::: zip xs ys
zip VZ VZ = VZ
```

— But now I cannot make use of inductive reasoning anymore:

```
Vector.hs:25:47: error:
    • Could not deduce: n2 ~ n1
      from the context: n ~ (n1 + 1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   ::: :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a,
                 in an equation for ‘zip’
        at Vector.hs:25:6-13
      or from: n ~ (n2 + 1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   ::: :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a,
                 in an equation for ‘zip’
        at Vector.hs:25:17-24
      ‘n2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          ::: :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a,
        in an equation for ‘zip’
        at Vector.hs:25:17-24
      ‘n1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          ::: :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a,
        in an equation for ‘zip’
        at Vector.hs:25:6-13
      Expected type: Vector n1 b
        Actual type: Vector n2 b
    • In the second argument of ‘zip’, namely ‘ys’
      In the second argument of ‘(:::)’, namely ‘zip xs ys’
      In the expression: (x, y) ::: zip xs ys
    • Relevant bindings include
        ys :: Vector n2 b (bound at Vector.hs:25:23)
        xs :: Vector n1 a (bound at Vector.hs:25:12)
   |
25 | zip (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) = (x, y) ::: zip xs ys
   |                                               ^^
```

Am I failing to observe something obvious? These `TypeLits` cannot be useless?.. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: "These TypeLits cannot be useless?..." - you're currently experiencing Stage 1, Denial

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, they're certainly limited, but I wouldn't go as far as to call them *useless*. One thing they're good for is APIs. `type family ToRealNat (n :: TL.Nat) :: Nat where {ToRealNat 0 = 'Z; ToRealNat n = 'S (ToRealNat (n-1))}`. You can also go the other way. That provides a much nicer interface than making users type in their Peano numerals by hand.

Comment: @dfeuer How safe is this? It is evident that, for n < 0, the function is undefined. I gave it a try in repl, and it appears that the type synonym would simply be left unresolved. I wonder if that is the defined behaviour, rather than compiler stack overflow. And whether there is a way to bake in the `n >= 0` restriction.

Comment: @dfeuer And how is that supposed to work? A definition like `type V (n :: TL.Nat) = Vector (ToRealNat n); zip' :: V n a -> V n b -> V n (a, b); zip' = zip` typechecks, but its call site does not, even with type annotations. _(Unless the vector is trivial, that is, `VZ`)_.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov, you probably want something like `class (n' ~ ToRealNat n, n ~ FromRealNat n') => ToRealNatC n n'; instance (n' ~ ToRealNat n, n ~ FromRealNat n') => ToRealNatC n n'; zip' :: ToRealNatC n n' => Vector n' a -> Vector n' b -> Vector n' (a, b)`. That will give you much better inference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no induction on `TypeLits`, which by default does make them nearly useless, but you can improve the situation in two ways.

**Use [`ghc-typelits-natnormalise`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise-0.6.2/docs/GHC-TypeLits-Normalise.html)**. It's a GHC plugin which adds an arithmetic solver to the type checker, and causes GHC to consider many equal `Nat` expressions equal. This is very convenient and is compatible with the next solution. Your `zip` works with this out of the box.

**Postulate whatever properties you need.** You should only postulate proofs of true statements, and only proofs of equalities or other computationally irrelevant data types, in order to avoid potential memory safety issues. For example, your `zip` works the following way:

```
{-# language
    RankNTypes, TypeApplications, TypeOperators,
    GADTs, TypeInType, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Equality
import Unsafe.Coerce

data Vector (n :: Nat) a
  where
    VZ :: Vector 0 a
    (:::) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a

lemma :: forall n m k. (n :~: (m + 1)) -> (n :~: (k + 1)) -> m :~: k
lemma _ _ = unsafeCoerce (Refl @n)

vzip :: Vector n a -> Vector n b -> Vector n (a, b)
vzip VZ VZ = VZ
vzip ((a ::: (as :: Vector m a)) :: Vector n a)
     ((b ::: (bs :: Vector k b)) :: Vector n b) =
  case lemma @n @m @k Refl Refl of
    Refl -> (a, b) ::: vzip as bs
```

Comment: By chance you know the reasoning behind _not_ providing induction on `Nat` in GHC/base by default? For instance, is it hard, but planned, or is it dangerous and forbidden?

Comment: No particular reason. My impression is that `TypeLits` was initially intended as no more than a second-class syntactic sugar. While `Nat` is now fairly good with the plugin, `Symbol` is still just a black-box with not many operations, and is mainly used to abstract over record field names and such.

Comment: You can even postulate an induction principle: `indNat :: p 0 -> (forall k. p k -> p (k+1)) -> SNat n -> p n`. Each such principle has two variants: a constant-time version when `p` only has one constructor (e.g., equality evidence) and a version that actually builds up the result value step by step.

Comment: (The constant-time version is dangerous, of course, since the passed function may not be total.)

Comment: @dfeuer I think this would be very useful as a library.

Comment: Apparently it already does exist as a library https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singleton-typelits